# Google+ Photo Backup Failed

Tags: google-plus

I have an HTC Inspire and I'm trying to use the new Google+ auto backup. All the photos say "Backup Failed". However, it is uploading the videos.  I have checked every setting that I know of and it looks like it is setup right.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set your photos to be uploaded when there is Wi-Fi or mobile data or just when there is Wi-Fi? Do you have a good Wi-Fi connection? Are you trying to "Back up all" to backup your previous photos?

Answer (score 1):

This method seems to work for me: Try deleting Google+ data/cache, then start Google+ app. It will log you in and then you can choose Auto Backup setting. You can then go to Sync settings, untick "Sync Google+ Auto Backup" and then tick it again. You can also go to the Google+ app settings and get it to upload all your photos/videos to start the sync.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advice from this post: http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/google-plus-discuss/d3s4VKI3yWo/bq39QiqknWoJ

> Another solution that worked for me was turning off Standard size in
> the Auto Backup settings altogether. When taking a new 8MP jpg using
> my camera and when Photo Size was set to Full Size in Google+, all the
> photos seem to be successfully uploading without error. This further
> confirms that the error is arising when Google+ is trying to convert
> larger jpgs to standard size.

I tried taking pictures at different resolutions, from 1.9MP - 8MP. 3.8MP and below uploaded without a problem. Anything with a higher resolution still failed.

So, the solution for now seems to be:

- take pictures at a lower resolution

  or
- Change the Photo Size setting in Auto Backup from "Standard size" to "Full size"